# shutil.copytree permission denied when copied sys32/config

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to copy the entire folder config under c:\windows\system32 and it copies some of the files that are not being used by another process and the rest get failed due to permission as it says. I run the code under admin privileges but still not copying SAM,SYSTEM,SECURITY ..etc.

It isn't a windows thing as I have applied this code on 3 machines with admin privileges and all of them have the same issues. is there any way to get around this issue?

Here is the code:

```
def copyDirectory():
    try:
        path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\config"
        dest = "Event"
        shutil.copytree(path, dest)
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
    except OSError as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
```

Comment: this isn't a python question, more a windows question

Comment: you can ignore errors with copytree

Comment: Try to change the `copy_function` argument to `shutil.copyfile`: `shutil.copytree(path, dest, copy_function=shutil.copyfile)`. In some particular circumstances copying the permissions using the default `shutil.copy2` can fail. `copyfile` does not preserve permissions, it just copies file contents. If you are on python2.7 there is no `copy_function` parameter unfortunately.

Comment: Those files constitute the Windows Registry, it makes sense that they are opened and locked by an OS process.  To reliably copy such files you need to use the Volume Shadow Copy infrastructure or perhaps shell out to reg.exe with an export command line.

Comment: As @AlexK. said the configuration manager stores the default profile, system, software, sam, and security hives here. The hive files are opened in the system process (PID 4) without read, write, or delete sharing. You can't even access the system process to duplicate the File handles, not without installing a driver. You need a volume shadow copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try to right click the parent folder, chose properties, go to Security tab, then make sure the user account you are trying to use to make changes has the write permissions. May as well just try giving your user account all of the available permissions while there.
2. As I have read somewhere else, you may need to also verify under General tab of properties that the folder is not 'read-only'.
3. If it is a shared folder, then under Sharing tab of properties, click "Advanced Sharing", the "Permissions", then add proper user account permissions there.